# Getting indexpath of tableview row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have M13Checkbox inside cell in tableView. When user cheks this checkbox I want to save some data in core data

```
- (IBAction)completed:(M13Checkbox *)sender {


    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSNumber *yes = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObject *selectedHabit = [self.habits objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
    self.habit = selectedHabit;

    NSNumber *habitID = [self.habit valueForKey:@"habitID"];

    NSNumber *habitRepeats = [self.habit valueForKey:@"habitRepeats"];

    //getting number of habit reoeats for Smart habits function
    int i = [habitRepeats intValue] + 1;
    NSNumber *repeats = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
    [self.habit setValue:repeats forKey:@"habitRepeats"];

    //saving completion to core data
    NSManagedObject *habitForDate = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"HabitForDate" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [habitForDate setValue:now forKey:@"date"];
    [habitForDate setValue:habitID forKey:@"habitID"];
    [habitForDate setValue:yes forKey:@"completed"];

    [context deleteObject:habitForDate];

     NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Althoug habits in tableview have different values for key "habitID", habitForDate always recives "1" as value for "habitID" I think the issue is in  below part of the code and I am getting wrong index

```
 NSManagedObject *selectedHabit = [self.habits objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
    self.habit = selectedHabit;
```

My question is, how to get indexPath of cell in which checkbox is cliked

Comment: Somebody down voted my perfectly fine answer below, but one another easiest way to do is to use tag. checkbox.tag = indexPath.row and later in your handler code you can construct indexPath based on your checkbox tag.

Comment: I think you can set property for example tag in M13Checkbox in cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate like `yourcheckbox.tag = indexPath.row` and when u call function - get right number.

Comment: That method worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)completed:(M13Checkbox *)sender {
    UITableViewCell * cell = [[sender superView] superView]; // if you added it to cell's content view.
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForCell:cell];

    ....
}
```

Comment: Care to explain? (LQRQ)

Comment: This will work, but is fragile since it is reliant on the the hierarchy of the UITableViewCell staying the same.

Comment: Indeed it would be better to use a custom table view with a property to the control.

Answer (score -1):

One of the way i do it is use category UIView+Data.h and attach extra piece of data to it.

```
#import "UIView+Data.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

const char * const viewUserDataKey = "view.userData";
@implementation UIView (Data)
- (id)userData {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, viewUserDataKey);
}

- (void)setUserData:(id)userData {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, viewUserDataKey, userData, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
@end
```

Also, have a property, `@property (nonatomic, strong) id userData;` in header file.

You can import this above category on your class and attach indexPath to your checkbox inside cell as `checkBox.userData = indexPath` I am not sure if it's the perfect way but my app is out in App Store and working fine!

And, in your method you can read back indexPath as

```
- (IBAction)completed:(M13Checkbox *)sender {
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath*)sender.userData;
}
```

Comment: this is a violation of MVC.